# how to limit the number of characters in a particular line(in my case i need third/second line of every cell) in tableview cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm new to iOS. These is my current code do and want to remove the character behind that button and when I press that button it show like these

[image]

I did that code but i want help in limit that character in that line where show more button appear.

[image]

Comment: That's a bit of a complex task... There is an open-source version that someone did which does just what you're asking. You could use it as-is, or it would be a good piece of code for you to review if you want to write your own: https://github.com/apploft/ExpandableLabel

Comment: thanks but its not going to help me because it written in shift.

Comment: *"its not going to help me"* -- it's simple to integrate Swift with Objective-C, so you *could* use it directly. Or, take a read through it anyway... code is code. If you can write in Obj-C, *reading* Swift is easy.

Comment: okay man, i will give a try.